# Show that $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ is non-singular near zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that  $\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}$ is non-singular near zero. Does this show boundedness near zero?

Comment: I never heard about singularity near the point. Usually they say "singular at the point".

Comment: The purpose is to show that the integral of this function is around a small circle around zero goes to zero as the radius of he circle goes to zero.Perhaps I should have written $z(e^z-1)$

Comment: Oops I meant $z/(e^z-1)

Answer (score 1):

It has a limit as $x\to0$, by, for example, l'Hopital. What conclusion about non-singularity and boundedness can you draw from this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you know the limit of the reciprocal as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By use of Taylor series, you can find the order of the zero that $e^x-1$ has at $x=0$. You can also find the order of the zero that $x$ has at $x=0$.

You can then combine this information to determine which of

- a removable singularity
- a pole (and its order)
- a zero (and its order)

that $x/(e^x-1)$ has at $x=0$.

In the case of a removable singularity, this method will also let you discover the value that $x/(e^x-1)$ would have at $x=0$ after removing the singularity. This winds up being mostly equivalent to using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: But the function is on a Riemann surface with a slit along the negative axis.

Comment: Er, neither $x$ nor $e^x-1$ has a branch cut, and so neither does $x/(e^x-1)$. In fact, the latter is very clearly continuous for all $x \neq 2 \pi \mathbf{i} n$ (and happens to be continuous for $n=0$).

Comment: The actual function is $((-x)^s)/((e^x-1)x)$ integrated around a tiny circle of radius delta , where s is fixed and x is the variable of integration . The book states that -x is defined as exp[slog(-x)]. Then claims that this goes to zero as delta goes to zero because $x/(e^x-1)$ is non-singular near 0.

Comment: It would depend upon what $s$ is. Presumably you factor the function as $$-\frac{x}{e^x - 1} \frac{(-x)^{s}}{x^2}$$ and analyze each factor separately.

Comment: I think $x/(e^x -1)$ need to be shown to be bounded ( non-singular) in the SPLIT neighborhood of 0.